# How to stop renderer(_:updateAtTime:) function in ARSCNView?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I use **renderer(_:updateAtTime:)** function to change position of object in scene

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    cylinder.position = SCNVector3(0, sin(time), 0)
}
```

So, if I want to stop scene, which displays in ARSCNView, I try to use following code

```
ARSceneView.scene.isPaused = true
```

but it didn't help, so my object is still moving instead staying in place (because renderer function is still be called every frame)

So how can I stop scene in ARSCNView?
or
How can I stop calling renderer(_:updateAtTime:) function?

Comment: Is `cylinder.position` still being modified, or is the object moving with the camera and you want it to freeze its position on screen?

Comment: cylinder.position is still being modified.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution how to stop `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` instance method. I could offer you a simple and robust workaround instead:

```
let action = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0, sin(time), 0), duration: 2)
let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeat(action, count: 1)
cylinderNode.runAction(repeatAction)
```

Hope this helps.